# List is not public; cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, android

This is my adapter named.... `CheckListAdapter` in here only I am getting the data from the database and show it in the listview... after that I here only getting checked items from the listview but i cannot understand it also.

```
public class CheckListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    ViewHolder holder;
    ArrayList<CheckList_Items> arrEmps;
    public CheckListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<CheckList_Items> map) {
        mContext = c;
        arrEmps = map;
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return getCount();
    }
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arrEmps.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return arrEmps.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View grid = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checklist, null);
            grid.setMinimumHeight(150);
            holder.name = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.t1);
            holder.box = (CheckBox) grid.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            grid.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) grid.getTag();
        }
        CheckList_Items p = getCheckList_Items(position);
        holder.name.setText(arrEmps.get(position).getName());
        holder.box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangeList);
        holder.box.setTag(position);
        holder.box.setChecked(p.getChecked());
        return grid;
    }
    CheckList_Items getCheckList_Items(int position) {
        return ((CheckList_Items) getItem(position));
    }
    ArrayList<CheckListAdapter> getBox() {
        ArrayList<CheckListAdapter> checked = new ArrayList<CheckListAdapter>();
        for (CheckList_Items p : arrEmps) {
            if (p.getChecked())
                checked.add(p);
        }
        return checked;
    }
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckChangeList = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                     boolean isChecked) {
            getCheckList_Items((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).checked = isChecked;
        }
    };
    class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        CheckBox box;
    }
}
```

This is the class named `CheckList_Items`

```
public class CheckList_Items {
    boolean checked;
    String name;
    public CheckList_Items(String name) {
      //  this.empID = empID;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public boolean getChecked() {
        return checked;
    }
    public void setSelected(boolean check) {
        checked = check;
    }
}
```

i faced the errors in these lines...I changed many types but i cannot get the output only getting errors

```
   getCheckList_Items((Integer) buttonView.getTag()).checked = isChecked;
```

error: checked is not public in CheckList_Items; cannot be accessed from outside package

```
            checked.add(p);
```

error: no suitable method found for add(CheckList_Items)
                checked.add(p);

Anyone help me on this...
thanks..

Comment: Instead of trying to set `.checked` directly, use your setter method, which (for some reason) is called `setSelected`. That is what setters are for.

Comment: @khelwood if i use setselected the error message is... error: method setSelected in class CheckList_Items cannot be applied to given types;

Comment: Cannot be applied to what given types? What types are you giving to it?

Answer (score 1):

add `public` in front of `getCheckList_Items`

right now it is package private

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an item with type `CheckList_Items` to a list of `CheckListAdapter`, replace :

```
ArrayList<CheckListAdapter> getBox() {
        ArrayList<CheckListAdapter> checked = new ArrayList<CheckListAdapter>();
        for (CheckList_Items p : arrEmps) {
            if (p.getChecked())
                checked.add(p);
        }
        return checked;
    }
```

with :

```
ArrayList<CheckList_Items> getBox() {
    ArrayList<CheckList_Items> checked = new ArrayList<CheckList_Items>();
    for (CheckList_Items p : arrEmps) {
        if (p.getChecked())
            checked.add(p);
    }
    return checked;
}
```